# sublime text: How do I know what font (or font string) to use when configuring font_face setting?

Tags: sublimetext3

The question applies to both windows and Macs. But I'm on an iMac at the moment so I can only test on a Mac.

I installed the mononoki Nerd Font.

In Font Book/Microsoft Word/Textedit (which is like a macOS Wordpad equivalent), the font is called “mononoki Nerd Font Mono”.

As a test, I tried setting my font_face to these and it's not working:

```
- "font_face": "mononoki Nerd Font Mono"
- "font_face": "mononoki Nerd Font Mono Regular"
```

and no change on my display. The text looks the same with and without the line above.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just `"Mononoki"`?

Comment: Or `"Mononoki Nerd Font"`? Also, did you save your preferences after making the changes?

Answer (score 2):

in Windows you can open fonts settings and search for your font, and there are two things:

1. Font Family
2. Font Face

eg. I want a font called fira code retina, which is in fira code font-family so I'll search for it in fonts settings:

[image: Font Settings under System Settings in Windows Settings]

Now the font-faces which comes under this family will be listed below:
[image]

Then you can select the font family name and get all the details of it.
[image]

Comment: thanks you. To display icon Nerd Font in Sublime text must set full name.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Settings in Sublime Text like so:

[image: Sublime Text picture]

Then, change the user settings like so with `font_face` property:

[image: Add font face]

Save the preferences and see if that changes your font. In the above example, I have chosen `American Typewriter` as the font_face and the effect is noticed upon save.

Give that a shot.

Comment: I couldn't tell if OP was doing that. Showing pictures of settings could help OP and others having similar issue. OP can respond if this process was followed. Further troubleshooting can happen after that.